# DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Am trying to start pentaho, but am getting the below mentioned error

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin/bin/java
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/nathan/biserver-ce/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/nathan/biserver-ce/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/nathan/biserver-ce/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/nathan/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

I have given the java_home path too. Still am getting error and unable to start pentaho. Please help

Comment: What error?  You say "below mentioned error" but then you don't tell us what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The clues are here:

```
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin/bin/java
```

It thinks that the path for the Java command is "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/bin/bin/java".  That is clearly wrong.  (".../bin/bin/..."?   Really??)

Working backwards, the launch script has done that because you have pointed the _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME variable at the "bin" directory.  That is incorrect.  It should point at the top directory of the JRE or JDK; i.e. either:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/
```

or

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/
```

(I suspect that either will work if you have a JDK install ... as you apparently do here.)